# Firebase Google sign in issue

Tags: android, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to implement google signin using firebase and i'm getting the following error :
**Google sign in failed com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10:**
I have already excecuted the following attempts:

- Added SHA1 key to the firebase project settings
- Linked android studio to firebase login
- I have created OAuth 2.0 client ID as **webclientid**
- I did not publish my project's APK on google play store. which means I did not accidentally generate another SHA1 fingerprint.

here is my code snippet:

```
package com.example.audiotransacriber;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 234;

    //Tag for the logs optional
    private static final String TAG = "data";

    //creating a GoogleSignInClient object
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

    //And also a Firebase Auth object
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        //first we intialized the FirebaseAuth object
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("302614807658-u9hs4aei98f66gpu21me3p7srj9vgine.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        findViewById(R.id.loginbut).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //skipping firebase siginin

        //if the user is already signed in
        //we will close this activity
        //and take the user to profile activity
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //if the requestCode is the Google Sign In code that we defined at starting
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

            //Getting the GoogleSignIn Task
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                //Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

                //authenticating with firebase
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        //getting the auth credential
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

        //Now using firebase we are signing in the user here
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User Signed In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }


    //this method is called on click
    private void signIn() {
        //getting the google signin intent
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();

        //starting the activity for result
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the debug SHA1 and the webclient id which is available in firebase project under Authentication - > Signin method -> Google sigin.